# Spring MVC internalization, only english messages are displayed. But the address bar changes

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization

--------------------UPDATE!-------------here is my .jsp  withouth unnecessairy buttons

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<html>
<head>

<title>Practice</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/wort.css" />
</head>
<body>



    <a href="goToDictionary.html" class="practice_dictionary"><spring:message code="check.the.dictionary" />
        </a>

    <br>
    <a href="?lang=en" class="languageselectorEnglish">en</a>
    <a href="?lang=de" class="languageselectorGerman">de</a>
    <br>


</body>
</html>
```

----------------------------------Update ends here----------------------------------------

I have set up i18n to my web app using Spring MVC. It does not work.
When I click on the link:

`<a href="?lang=de">de</a>`

nothing happens, only the address bar changes to

```
http://localhost:8080/wort/register.html?lang=de
```

but the displayed messages remain the same (english).
Obviously I have the messages_de.properties file next to the messages_en.properties file. 
(there is no problem with the english messages' display.)

Do I miss something obvious?

here is my spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="net" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="handlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="interceptors">
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>net.model.Word</value>
                <value>net.model.Category</value>
                <value>net.model.Challenge</value>
                <value>net.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Please show your jsp content.

Comment: Did you use `native2ascii` for encoding properties file?

Comment: i never used it i have to check what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution: I have to remove this from spring-servlet.xml and everything is fine

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```